# SQL Server : how to set a max number of rows to return

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to limit the number of rows returned and although simple in regular code, can't find a way to do it using SQL Server. I have a table that can contains multiple rows per the same trade id and I want to just tag a max of 2 for deletion and only the first 2. So for example, I have the following:

```
Trade id 10, seq# 5, CR 1k
         10, seq# 6, DR 1k
         10, seq# 7, CR 1K
```

I want to tag seq# 5 & 6 for deletion as they offset each other via DR/CR and I want to leave seq#7 as is. Using a join I end up linking seq # 5&6, and 6 & 7 as I'm looking for rows where trade id & amount same but credit/debit fields are not =.  any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Row_Number` window function to do this.

```
select * from 
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by Trade_id order by seq_no asc) as RN
From Yourtable
)
Where RN<=2
```

To delete the records use `CTE`

```
;with cte as 
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by Trade_id order by seq_no asc) as RN
From Yourtable
)
delete from cte 
Where RN<=2
```